# Need to automate the updating of the crontab file

Tags: cron, upgrade

We have an automated process where a server is built, and after applications/middleware are installed using another automated process, and the crontab needs to be updated for those applications/middleware.  We are doing this using `crontab -e` at this point but would like to automate this so we can put it into the automated build.  Has anyone been able to automate `crontab -e`, or anything of the nature?

Thank you

Comment: crontab -e command edits the cron file under /var/spool/cron/username. Editing that file may work although its not recommaneded. "Each user can have their own crontab, and though these are files in /var/spool/ , they are not intended to be edited directly."

Comment: @alpertek: `crontab -e` obeys the `EDITOR` environment variable. I don't think `EDITOR` needs to be interactive, though, you could just set it to be the manipulation program.

Answer (score 2):

first step

```
 crontab -l > /tmp/foo
```

second step

process /tmp/foo (add entries)

```
 cat /tmp/foo /tmp/crontab.mycompany > /tmp/newcrontab
```

finaly

```
 cat /tmp/newcrontab | crontab -
```

to be done with either root or user.

if user is not root, most likely

```
 cat /tmp/crontab.mycompany.user | crontab -
```

as user will do.

Comment: Wouldn't `crontab < /tmp/newcrontab` or `crontab /tmp/newcrontab` be better than `cat...` ?